# String manipulation in Regex with seemingly too many exceptions

Tags: python, regex

In this post I am calling *strings* of the form (x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) a *sequence* and *strings* of the form {y<sub>1</sub>, ..., y<sub>n</sub>} a *set*. Where each x<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>i</sub> can be either a number `[0-9]+`, a word `[a-zA-Z]+`, a number/word `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, a sequence, or a set.

---

I want to know if it is at all possible (and if so, help figuring out how) to use Regex to deal with the following:

I want to transform sequences of the form (x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, x<sub>n+1</sub>) into ((x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>), x<sub>n+1</sub>).

Examples:

`(1,2,3,4,5)` will change to `((1,2,3,4),5)`

`((1,2,3,4),5)` will change to `(((1,2,3),4),5)` since the only string of the form (x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, x<sub>n+1</sub>) is the `(1,2,3,4)` on the inside.

`(((1,2,3),4),5)` will change to `((((1,2),3),4),5)` since the only string of the form (x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, x<sub>n+1</sub>) is the `(1,2,3)` on the inside.

`(1,(2,3),4)` will change to `((1,(2,3)),4)`

`({1},{2},{3})` will change to `(({1},{2}),{3})`

As per request, more examples:

`((1,2),(3,4),5)` will change to `(((1,2),(3,4)),5)`

`((1,2),3,(4,5))` will change to `(((1,2),3),(4,5))`

`(1,(2,(3,4),5))` will change to `(1,((2,(3,4)),5))` since the only sequence of the form (x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, x<sub>n+1</sub>) is the `(2,(3,4),5)` on the inside.

Here is what I have so far:

```
re.sub(r'([(][{}a-zA-Z0-9,()]+,[{}a-zA-Z0-9,]+),', r'(\g<1>),', string)
```

You can see the strings it works for [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/6/).

It is not working for `(1,(2,3),4)`, and it *is* working on things like `({{x},{x,y}},z)` when it shouldn't be. Any help is greatly appreciated; I feel like it is possible to get this to work in Regex but there seem to be a lot of special cases that require the Regex to be very precise.

Comment: Parsing recursive syntaxes (such as nested parentheses) is *not* a natural use case for regular expressions. It can be possible with particular regular expression extensions, but it's (IMHO) better to just use a parser generator to generator a parser.

Comment: What should `((1,(2,3)),4)` become if it was ran through the function?

Comment: @rici I am unfamiliar with parser generators; would you mind pointing me to resources where I can learn about them? Also, since it is not *natural* but possibly possible to parse recursive syntaxes with regex, which extensions would you be referring to?

Comment: @ctwheels `((1,(2,3)),4)` shouldn't become anything, it should remain the same. Because `((1,(2,3)),4)` is a sequence with only two parts, the first being `(1,(2,3))` and the second being `4`.

Comment: @anubhava When I said sequences of the form (x_1, ..., x_n, x_n+1) I meant for n > 1. So it should only work on sequences which have 3 or more entries.

Comment: If `n > 1` then it should not change `(1,(2,3),4)` since there are only 2 elements in `(2,3)`

Comment: @anubhava `(1,(2,3),4)`  has three entries. The first entry is `1`, the second entry is `(2,3)` and the third entry is `4`. So `(1,(2,3),4)` would change into `((1,(2,3)),4)`. Do you see why?

Comment: @Nika you should add more complex examples: `((1,2),(3,4),5)`, `((1,2),3,(4,5))`, `(1,(2,(3,4),5))`, `(((1,2),(3,(4,5))),(6,7))`, etc and clearly explain the rules. Which sequences can and which cannot be broken? What *exactly* is a sequence - what's it's form?

Comment: @ctwheels If adding more examples helps, then I'll do it. But my question is perfectly well formed, if you read the very top of my question (the first 2 sentences) you will be able to figure out which sequences the function can and which sequences the function cannot operate on.

Comment: @Nika I guess the confusion comes when you're talking about converting subsequences for some sets but not others: `((1,2,3),4)` becomes `(((1,2),3),4)`, but `(1,(2,3,4),5)` becomes what - `(1,((2,3),4),5)` or `((1,(2,3,4)),5)`?

Comment: @ctwheels `(1,(2,3,4),5)` could become either one of `(1,((2,3),4),5)` or `((1,(2,3,4)),5)`, whichever one is easier to make a function out of. Since no matter which one of those two `(1,(2,3,4),5)` becomes, when it is run through the function again they will both become the same thing, i.e., `((1,((2,3),4)),5)`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Nika thank you for the update, not sure if you missed the final form of `((1,2),(3,4),5)` in the update, I assume it's supposed to be `(((1,2),(3,4)),5)`?

Comment: @ctwheels Whoops, yeah I fixed it. Thanks for catching that one!

Comment: @Nika: Does this meet all your requirements? https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/7 (You will have to use regex module in Python)

Comment: @anubhava VERY close. I tested it and it does not work for `(1,{{1},{1,2}},3)`. It should change `(1,{{1},{1,2}},3)` to `((1,{{1},{1,2}}),3)`.

Comment: @Nika: Ok I am investigating that test case.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you! If it helps in any way, notice that it will work for `({1},{1,2},{1,2,3})` but not for `({{1}},{{1,2}},{{1,2,3}})`, when it should work for both. It is possible that the problem is that the double curly brackets throws off the match.

Comment: @Nika: I have updated answer with a *fix* and new demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any recursion in python, you'll have to use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (as mentioned by [anubhava in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363416/3600709)). You can use the following pattern:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/9)

```
(\((({(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))+})|\((?:[^(),]+,[^(),]+)\)|[^(){},]+)(?:,(?2))+),
```

Replace with `(\1),`

How it works:

- `(\((({(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))+})|\((?:[^(),]+,[^(),]+)\)|[^(){},]+)(?:,(?2))+),` capture the following into capture group 1, then match `,`

  - `\(` match `(` literally
  - `(({(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))+})|\((?:[^(),]+,[^(),]+)\)|[^(){},]+)` match one of the following options one or more times (and capture it into capture group 2)

    - `({(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))+})` capture the following into capture group 3
    - `{(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))+}` matches `{`, then one of the following options one or more times, then `}`

      - `[^{}]+` matches any character except `{` or `}` one or more times
      - `(?-1)` recurses the previous capture group (capture group 3)
    - `\((?:[^(),]+,[^(),]+)\)` matches `(`, then the following, then `)`
    - `[^(),]+` matches any character except `(`, `)`, or `,` one or more times
    - `,` matches the comma `,` character literally
    - `[^(),]+` matches any character except `(`, `)`, or `,` one or more times
    - `[^(){},]+` matches any character except `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, or `,` one or more times
  - `(?:,(?2))+` matches the following one or more times

    - `,(?2)` matches `,`, then recurses capture group 2

In simpler terms, capture group 2 defines what a **term** is. It...:

1. Matches any sets `{y1, ..., yn}` + recusively: `{{y1, ..., yn},..., xn}`
2. Matches any complete sequences of exactly two elements: `(x1, x2)`
3. Matches any string object (numbers, words, etc.) `1`, `2`, ... `x`, `y`, ...

Then capture group 1 uses the well-defined **terms** from capture group 2 to match as many terms as possible, with the string containing at least two terms and a comma (`x,x,` with as many `x,` as possible). The replacement takes this capture group, encases it in `()` and appends `,`. So in the case of `(x,x,x,x)`, we get `((x,x,x),x)`.

---

### Edit

By making the non-capture group possessive `(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))++` (prevents backtracking) and changing the order of the options (most prevalent first), we can improve the efficiency of the pattern (764 -> 662 steps):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/12)

```
(\(([^(){},]+|\((?:[^(),]+,[^(),]+)\)|({(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))++}))(?:,(?2))+),
```

Comment: This one works for the cases `(1,{{1},{1,2}},3)` which don't work in the other one! I'm going to keep throwing weird strings at it and see if it breaks on any of them but it looks like it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you can consider using [`PyPi regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) of Python that supports PCRE features then it is possible with recursive matching support using this regex:

```
/
(                                       # start capture group #1
  \(                                    # match left (
  (?<el>                                # start named group el
    ( { (?: [^{}]*+ | (?-1) )* } ) |    # Match {...} text OR
    ( \( (?: [^()]*+ | (?-1) )*+ \) ) | # Match (...) text OR
    \w+                                 # Match 1+ word characters
  )                                     # End named group el
  (?: , (?&el) )+                       # Match comma followed by recursion of 'el'
                                        # Match this group it 1+ times                                          
) ,                                     # End capture group #1
/ x                                     # Enable extended mode in regex
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/11)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple parser built with [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html)

It is certainly less compact than the regex solutions, but it has a couple of considerable advantages:

1. It's a lot easier to write and understand. (In fact, my first attempt worked perfectly except for a typo in one of the names.) Moreover, it is reasonably clear by examination exactly what syntax is being parsed. (This assumes some minimal understanding of generative grammars, of course, but the concepts are not particularly difficult and there are many available learning resources.)
2. If you want to add more features in the future, it's straight-forward to modify. If instead of just reformatting the text, you want to actually make some use of the decomposed structure, that is easily available without much effort.

As with most generated parsers, it has two components: a *lexer* (or scanner), which decomposes the input into tokens and discards unimportant text such as whitespace, and a *parser* which analyses the stream of tokens in order to figure out its structure. Normally a parser would construct some kind of data structure representing the input, normally some kind of tree. Here I've simplified the process by just recombining the parsed input into a transformed output. (In retrospect, I can't help thinking that, as usual, it would have been clearer to produce an entire parse tree and then create the output by doing a walk over the tree. Perhaps as penance I'll redo it later.)

Here's the scanner. The only meaningful tokens are the punctuation symbols and what I've called WORDs, which are sequences of whatever Python considers word characters (usually alphabetic and numeric characters plus underlines), without distinguishing between purely alphabetic, purely numeric, and mixed tokens as in your question.

```
import ply.lex as lex
tokens = [ "WORD" ]
t_WORD = r"\w+"
# Punctuation
literals = "{}(),"
# Ignore whitespace
t_ignore = " \r\n\t"
# Anything else is an error
def t_error(t):
     print("Illegal character %s" % repr(t.value[0]))
     t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()
```

Now the parser. The grammar for sequences is a little redundant because it has to special-case a sequence of one item: Since the grammar also explicitly inserts parentheses around `A,B` as it parses, it would be incorrect to add them around the entire sequence. But if the entire sequence is one item, the original parenthweses have to be reinserted. For sets, things are much clearer; the elements are not modified at all, the braces must always be added back.

Here's the entire grammar:

```
# scalar   : WORD | set | sequence

# sequence : '(' scalar ')'
#          | '(' seqlist ')'
# seqlist  : scalar  ',' scalar
#          | seqlist ',' scalar

# set      : '{' setlist '}'
# setlist  : scalar
#          | setlist ',' scalar
```

And here's the implementation, with the grammar repeated, Ply-style, as docstrings:

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
start = 'scalar'
def p_unit(p):
    """scalar   : WORD
                | set
                | sequence
       setlist  : scalar
    """
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_sequence_1(p):
    """sequence : '(' scalar ')'
    """
    p[0] = '(%s)' % p[2]

def p_sequence(p):
    """sequence : '(' seqlist ')'
    """
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_seqlist(p):
    """seqlist : scalar  ',' scalar
               | seqlist ',' scalar
    """
    p[0] = "(%s,%s)" % (p[1], p[3])

def p_set(p):
    """set     : '{' setlist '}'
    """
    p[0] = '{%s}' % p[2]

def p_setlist(p):
    """setlist : setlist ',' scalar
    """
    p[0] = "%s,%s" % (p[1], p[3])


def p_error(p):
     if p:
          print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
     else:
          print("Syntax error at EOF")

parser = yacc.yacc()
```

Now, a (very) simple driver:

```
import readline
while True:
    try:
        s = input('> ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    if s:
        print(parser.parse(s, lexer=lexer))
```